# Is a git subtree the right thing, to keep track of a sub git repository I also want to customize?

Tags: git

I want to use [this Jekyll theme](https://github.com/tomjohnson1492/documentation-theme-jekyll) in my repository. How can I keep track of this remote, sub repository, while a add or do my changes to the documentation in my repository?

Can I achieve this with a git subtree?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I achieve this with a git subtree?

## Short Answer

Yes.

## Long Answer

### Subtree and Submodules

You can use `subtree` or `submodule`. Both differ in concept and usage. For introduction with further links, have a look at:

- https://www.atlassian.com/blog/git/alternatives-to-git-submodule-git-subtree
- https://www.atlassian.com/blog/git/git-submodules-workflows-tips

### How to start

First, think about what you want to do:

- Just include the other project/theme?
- Only change your project and not the theme?
- Keep track of upstream changes?
- Change the theme yourself?
- Integrate upstream changes to the theme with your changes?
- Send your changes to the theme upstream?

If you already decided for one of the solutions: set up a simple repository as a playground and try to work through your use cases. Or better yet: try it with both `submodule` and `subtree` in different repositories and see which one works best for you.

### Bonus points

Put the commands you will use to implement your workflow into scripts, a Makefile, or similar automation or build tool.